# getchar() adding extra characters

Tags: c, linux, getchar

I'm writing a program where I input some words into `stdin` and there are several different functions that do different things. I'm going to focus on the third functionality here. The user inputs multiple words in one line and I am supposed to get the last word. The issue I'm having is very weird, basically, whenever I input a word that consists of 8 characters, the program prints out the last word correctly but also adds an additional letter 'Genu' to the end of the word. For a 9 letter word it adds 'enu' and so on. Words with 12 letters or more do not have this issue. Also, this is only happening on `Linux`. On `Winows` I'm getting this message: `@.

Here's the code:

```
int main(void)
{
     char* commands[2] = {"search", "exit"};

     char str[100];
     int ch, n = 0;

     while(1)
     {
          while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
         {
             str[n] = ch;

             n++;
         }

         char *lastword = str;

         for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         {
              if(str[i] == ' ')
              {
                  lastword = strrchr(str, ' ') + 1;
                  break;
              }
         }

        memset(str, 0, 100);
        n = 0;
    }

   return 0;
 }
```

Does anyone know what the issue may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like you're missing a null-byte. `str` is not initialized properly, that means that its contents are undefined initially. You can see that your program works for all further input, that is because you `memset` the buffer back to all zeroes. What you need is a zero right behind the last letter of the last word (i.e. `memset` the buffer *before* going into the while loop or initialize it like `char str[100] = {0};`)